# How to built the plain page using Ionic app?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am new to angular and ionic. I want to take a plain page and then do some work.I did not the plain ionic page. Is there any one for help me!!

Comment: it's not clear what you are asking at all.  you have tagged the `ionic-framework`, which uses `angularjs`, along with tagging `angular2`, which is used in `ionic2`.  you'll need to provide **a lot more information** about what you are trying to do, and use tags that actually match.

Comment: At first i want to take the plain page of ionic.How can i get the plain page of ionic app...

Comment: If I haven't been clear, this question isn't answerable the way it is written.  Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As you mension about angular and ionic i hope you are using ionic 1.

You can use below command to download plain or blank project.

> ionic start myApp blank

Better you go through below links.

[If you are using ionic 1 refer this link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/getting-started/).
[if you are using ionic 2 refer this link](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/).